# How can I speed up the insert of 1 Milion up to 4 milion document in my mongoDB?

Tags: database, spring, mongodb

I'm using Spring as framework and mongoDB as DB. I noticed that Mongo work quite well finding document but when it works with a big number of records it becomes very slow (more or less 6 minutes to save one milion of document).
In my database, in other table, there are lot of data (more or less 20 milion of records). Is it a problem?

How can I speed up the process?

I show you how I write data in Spring:

```java
@Document
public class Message {  
    @Id
    private String id; 
    ...other 20 fields with getter and setter...
}
```

In order to save data I tried:

First Attempt:

```java
mongotemplate.insertAll(messages)
```

Second attempt:

```java
BulkOperations bulkOp = mongotemplate.bulkOps(BulkMode.UNORDERED , Message.class);
    bulkOp.insert(messages.parallelStream()
    .map(Message::flatToTmpMessage) // map a DtoMessage into Message
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    long nMessage = bulkOp.execute().getInsertedCount();
```

Third attempt:

```java
List<Document> documents = messages.parallelStream()
    .map(Message::flatToDocument) // I create a Bson from DtoMessage foreach document
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
String collectionName = mongotemplate.getCollectionName(Message.class);
mongotemplate.getCollection(collectionName).insertMany(documents);
```

Actually, the last one is slightly better than the others but none of them really satisfy me.
How can I reduce the time of writing?
Is it convenient to use another type of database (like Cassandra or an SQL one)? If the answer is yes which one is the fastest one to write up to 4 Million records in an almost empty table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered sharding?

Comment: What is your expectation?

Comment: @barrypicker: we have a replica set but it seems that only one server handles write operations.

Comment: @prasad_: we hope in seconds not minutes

Comment: Inserting 1-4 million records - what kind of application is this?

Comment: Write operations are expected to be performed only on the primary server of a replica set then replicated to secondaries.  Replica sets are for high-availability not high-performance.  If you want high-performance you may want to consider sharding.